# The loading pygame image is randomly filling the screen

Tags: python-3.x, image, pygame

I am having a problem with pygame loading the image. This is the code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

pygame.time.delay(900)

scr=pygame.display.set_mode((626,626))

pygame.display.update()

pygame.display.set_caption("Cricket")

bg=pygame.image.load('C:/Users/asus/Documents/Python Files/Cricket Application/bg.jpg').convert()

scr.blit(bg,(0,0))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            break
```

When I run it, the screen either does not get filled, either a little bottom piece will, or either the left piece will.

I cannot understand why is this happening.

(The image is in as the same folder as the .py file is)
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use .convert() in after loading the image.
That is not necessary.

Except that don't use break function in the code after calling pygame.quit(), instead just use quit().

Avoid providing a directory for the image instead paste the image in the same folder as the python file and just write the name of the image file in the code.

Also, Remember to resize the image before using it.

Final Code Should Look Like This:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

pygame.time.delay(900)

scr=pygame.display.set_mode((626,626))

pygame.display.update()

pygame.display.set_caption("Cricket")

bg=pygame.image.load('image.jpg')

scr.blit(bg,(0,0))

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type==pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
```

Comment: You half helped me, and I half helped myself. Use ```pygame.display.update()``` for showing the image.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that. But the image showed up in the above program.